# Asynchronous Post with HttpWebRequest in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

I've run come across a behavior with HttpWebRequest that I believe is intended, but as I have not been able to find any source that definitively says this is correct, I thought I would post it as a question and see if anyone has encountered this and/or can verify this is correct.

For starters I have an MVC3 app running on IIS 7.5.  It has 1 controller and supports 1 post method.  I have Windows Auth and ASP.NET Impersonation enabled within IIS.  The idea behind the MVC3 app is just to have a simple service that can be used for logging information from a variety of client applications(console apps, silverlight, asp.net, AJAX, etc).  One of the things the service does is uses the User property from the controller to also log who the person who posted data to this service.

To simplify the processing for the consuming applications I created some client libraries, Silverlight, DotNet, and a js library.

This all worked out as expected except when using the DotNet library within another MVC3 application.  For the DotNet library I'm using an HttpWebRequest and using the asynchronous methods (Begin/EndGetRequestStream)/(Begin/EndGetResponse) to post the request.  I'm also setting the .Credentials on the request to CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials, but when the logging application starts the processing of the request from another MVC3 app it shows the User as the service account of the app pool from which the post was received.

When I found this I added a synchronous version of the post to the DotNet library and found that the logging service was using my personal credentials.

I assume that HttpWebRequest could be using different DefaultCredentials depending on the context in which it is used.  Since this is asp.net and the async method of the request are being called, my library code may not have even finished before the client MVC3 app has returned a response.

What I haven't been able to find is if this is definitively the case or not.  If anyone has and answer or or an article that could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this may seem like and odd question but what web browser are you using?

Comment: I am using IE 8.  I've figured out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I was encountering was intended behavior.  The root of the problem comes down to under which identity do threads from the .Net thread pool execute when servicing the asynchronous requests.  In my case the threads were executing as the owner of the app domain that was created by the app pool.  In my case it was a service account.

I was able to capture the identity of the impersonated user prior to the start of any asychronous processing and use the WindowsImpersonationContext to force my library code to run as the impersonated user.  By doing this CredentialsCache.DefaultCredentials used my credentials(impersonated user) instead of the account running the app pool when setting it on the HttpWebRequest instance.